# how to fetch datatype datetime value inside apex

Tags: apex

I have a custom field called `StartDate__C`  inside a custom object...`Test_Article__c` custom object.
Now i want to fetch this value inside the apex class...
I am doing something like:

```
public DateTime fromDate;

lst=[select ArTitle__c,StartDate__c,  from Test_Article__c where StartDate__c!=null];

if(lst!=null && lst.size()>0)
{
   lst[0].StartDate__c = fromDate;  
}
```

but the value assigned infromdate is showing as null..
how can i rectify this??

Comment: what is from date here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your requirement,you have to assign fromdate as the start date

Please check below,

```
public DateTime fromDate;

lst=[select ArTitle__c,StartDate__c,  from Test_Article__c where StartDate__c!=null];

if(lst!=null && lst.size()>0)
{
   fromDate=lst[0].StartDate__c;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to access a position of a collection type but not stating that 'lst' is a collection. Take a look at the following.

```
public DateTime fromDate;

List<Test_Article__c> lst= [
    select ArTitle__c,
      StartDate__c
    from Test_Article__c
    where StartDate__c != null];

if(lst.size() > 0) {
    fromDate = lst[0].StartDate__c;  
}
```

Take a look into [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_database/apex_database_soql) Trailhead based on SOQL. Gain an understanding from the beginning and it will all make sense.

Hope this helps.